# Exp:resso + MSM: Site parameter not available?

Tags: expresso-store

I don't see any reference to the site parameter in any of the docs, is this available in the current release? We have built a multi site enviro for a retailer that allows for one control panel (front facing) so the client does not need to access the actual EE cp, in order for this to work I need to use the store tags but specify the site
thanks

Answer (score 2):

Since Store tags operate on top of Channel Data if you add the `site_id` parameter to the channel entries tag Store will be displaying the proper items based upon that. So for example

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="products" site_id="2"}
 {exp:store:products entry_id="{entry_id}"
  <h2>{title}</h2>
  <h3>{price}</h3>
 {/exp:product:price}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Would only show products for the site 2 so you wouldnt need to add site_id to the product tags.

Comment: Actually I have a feeling the products tag is always restricted to the current site. For example, you can't add products from multiple sites to your cart.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure exactly which tag you need the site parameter on.

Store is Multi-site Manager compatible and stores the site ID on the carts and orders in the database.

If you're trying to show orders from the front-end, the `{exp:store:orders}` tag automatically uses the current site id to filter the results.

If you need to override that and show orders from another site on the front-end, you'll likely need to write an add-on to do so or use the query module.